# ggplot2 How to subsetting a value from a DataFrame which have a list of theses?

Tags: r, ggplot2

That's for covid data

I have seen a example code from internet to plot a world map which have a lot of variables. Like name (of the country), confirm (cases), suspect, dead, heal, showRate, and the deadRate

But I only know (by the example) how to plot the confirmed cases, and I want to plot dead toll and the deadRate, but I don´t know how to do it

for work with this code you must install these package:

```
remotes::install_github("GuangchuangYu/nCov2019")
```

To get the latest data, you can load it in with `get_nCov2019()`.

```
library(nCov2019)
x <- get_nCov2019(lang='en')
```

so... to Getting a plot of the world map is really simple. There are only three lines needed:

```
require(nCov2019)
x = get_nCov2019(lang='en')
plot(x)
```

but these code plot the cumulative cases.

If you want to see the all values for all the countries you can use these line:

```
View(x['global'])
```

But I want to plot the dead toll instead cumulative cases- How can to do it?

I have seen the code and the information here: [link to the URL](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-r-package-to-explore-the-novel-coronavirus-590055738ad6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any reason inside that package (I can not see the settings for the map plot), it is always taking the confirmed serie and plotting it. You can do a trick by replacing the values in confirmed cases by those from death rate and then format the plot. Here the code to hack the plot scheme:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(nCov2019)
#Get data
x <- get_nCov2019(lang='en')
#Trick the variable
x$global$confirm <- as.numeric(trimws(x$global$deadRate))
#Plot
G1 <- plot(x)
#Modify
G1 <- G1+labs(subtitle = 'Death rate')+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

You can further customize the plot with other elements present in `ggplot2`.

Comment: don´t work for me the part of #modify, but I can make the plot with plot(x)

Comment: @Raul Hi. Maybe an issue package try updating `ggplot2` and also invoke `tidyverse` package!